# How to test a survival model on left- and right-censoring dataset

Tags: survival, model-evaluation

My dataset contains only left-censoring and right-censoring data. There is not any non-censoring data. The data is then split into training and test sets. How should I test the performance of a Weibull survival model on the test set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no fundamental problem with having only censored data in your dataset, though if they are all censored at the same place you will not be able to differentiate between distributions with identical probabilities on either side of a single censoring point.  Assuming you have censoring occurring at different points, you should be able to proceed using standard estimation techniques.  Without loss of generality, I will assume you have a random split of data into a training set with $n$ data points and a test set with $m$ data points.

**Fitting your data on the training set:** To facilitate your analysis, suppose your training set has $n$ data points with censored values $x_1, ..., x_n$ and corresponding indicators $c_1,..., c_n$, with $c_i=0$ for left-censoring and $c_i = 1$ for right-censoring.  For an underlying [Weibull distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution), this fully censored data yields the likelihood function:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
L_{\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{c}}(k, \lambda) 
&= \prod_{i=1}^n F(x_i|k,\lambda)^{1-c_i} (1-F(x_i|k,\lambda))^{c_i} \\[6pt]
&= \Big[ \prod_{c_i=0} F(x_i|k,\lambda) \Big] \Big[ \prod_{c_i=1}  (1-F(x_i|k,\lambda)) \Big] \\[6pt]
&= \Big[ \prod_{c_i=0} (1 - \exp(- (x_i/\lambda)^k) \Big] \Big[ \prod_{c_i=1}  \exp(- (x_i/\lambda)^k) \Big]. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

This likelihood function can be further simplified using the binomial expansion, and you can obtain estimates $\hat{k}$ and $\hat{\lambda}$ from your training data.  This can be done via maximum-likelihood estimation, or Bayesian estimation, or other methods.

**Testing against the test set:** Now suppose your test data contains $m$ data points with censored values $x_{n+1},...,x_{n+m}$ and corresponding indicators $c_{n+1},...,c_{n+m}$.  The simplest test would be to treat the censoring values as fixed and test whether your training estimates give you reasonable predictions of which side of the censored value the observation falls (i.e., whether the data point is left-censored or right-censored).  Based on your training set, you have estimated probabilities:

$$\hat{p}_{n+i} \equiv \hat{\mathbb{P}}(c_{n+i} = 1|x_{n+i}) = 1-F(x_{n+i}|\hat{k},\hat{\lambda}) = \exp(- (x_{n+i}/\hat{\lambda})^\hat{k}).$$

You can compare these estimated probabilities against the observed values of $c_{n+1},...,c_{n+m}$ to see whether you are predicting the area where the variable falls correctly.  This can be done by considering the $C$ values as Bernoulli random variables, and looking at your capacity to predict these accurately from your estimates from your training data.

Comment: (+1) More generically, you can compute the likelihood over the test data.

Comment: Ben and @CliffAB Thanks for your help. My data points are censored at the different places. In particular, most left-censored data are censored at somewhere within time [0.2, 0.5], while most right-censored data are censored at time [0.05, 0.1]. The rest 30% of the data are either left- or right-censored at [0.1, +inf]. Currently, I build a Weibull survival model and have been using the simplest test you suggested. The Weibull survival model is compared with a classic Logistic Regression, which treats the censored time point as the target (assuming they are not censored).

Comment: But I get some concerns: 1) The accuracy and AUC are "abnormally" high (i.e., ~95%). So I guess the simplest test is “too easy” for my data. For instance, it may be easy to predict the occurrence of right-censoring at an early time point. 2) The classic logistics regression performs slightly better than the the Weibull survival model (also tried other distributions). It seems that this simplest test is identical to a traditional classification test. I am thinking whether the simplest test has bias to the traditional classification method (e.g logistic regression), instead of survival methods.

Comment: @Munichong: yes, the AUC may be high because for various values of $t$, it can be very easy to determine whether it is right or left censored. In regards to logistic regression, *if all your data is right or left censored*, then using logistic regression with $\log(t)$ as a predictor is actually equivalent to a certain survival regression model: proportional odds with a log-logistic baseline. So that it may preform slightly better is not too shocking. But if your data includes uncensored values, don't use logistic regression.

Comment: @CliffAB Do you think C-index and Brier score can be good alternatives, instead of traditional AUC?